# Prevent touches on a View android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, floating-action-button

After some tries i am able to generate a semi-transparent background when i click my floatingbutton. The problem right now is that the "new background" only change the color. Under this, i have a recycleview and i still can swype up or down and have interactions with it. What i need right now is prevent every actions with the recyclerview under the layout that i make visible. The only thing i can do is:

- If i click on the semi-transparent view the fab collapse

This is the code that actually use:

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (DrawerActivity.instance.rootFab.isExpanded())
            {
                whiteLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            { 
                whiteLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
            mainFab.toggle();
        }
    };
```

and of course:

```
rootFab.setAddButtonClickListener(listener);
```

to give it the listener. So, simply, click on the main fab (i use a library with multiple fabs) and it makes visible the layout that is like:

```
----
----
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/status"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/semi_white_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white_semi_transparent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </LinearLayout>
---
---
```

And if i press fab again the layout disappear... So my question is, how can i do the same thing but click over this background but without "touch" the recyclerview over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell Android that your view is "clickable". This way your view will consume touch events and they are not going to be passed further to your `RecyclerView`.

To mark view as "clickable" just add following flag into your xml layout: `android:clickable="true"`:

```
----
----
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/status"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/semi_white_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white_semi_transparent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </LinearLayout>
---
---
```

Also if you use your view as just a background - I don't see any reason why you need heavy-weight `LinearLayout`. You can just use `View` here:

```
----
----
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/status"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/semi_white_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white_semi_transparent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />
---
---
```

Comment: Yes, right infact i was update the code with the View. By the way, correct! Now my view is marked as clickable. And i can't touch the RecyclerView anymore. But can i create an onClick method on the view to make possible that if touched the fab collapse and the view disappear? Even if now is android:clickable="true"?

Comment: sure, `onClickListener` still can be added